# Binding a JSON Array of strings to ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to post an array of JSON strings to MVC3 without a custom binder? The array is being created from checkbox values and I'm posting it via jQuery as follows:

```
var checkedItems = $(":checked").map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    $.post("/test/delete", { Items: checkedItems });
```

The raw post query strings looks like this:

```
Items%5B%5D=test1.com&Items%5B%5D=test2.com&Items%5B%5D=test3.com
```

I had a look at the MVc3 source and it appears that I need to use index values like [0], [1]. If MVC3 can't natively bind the array is there a simple way to change the post values so they have the index values required by MVC3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the content type to asp.net mvc so that is reads it as json, use jquery ajax function like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/test/delete",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({Items: checkedItems}),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
```

and get json2.js to make json.stringify available on browser that do not supoprt it

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the array

```
{ Items: JSON.stringify(checkedItems) }
```

And then decode it on the other side. But be careful - JSON.stringify isn't available in IE7.

Comment: Get json2.js, it will add JSON.stringify when it isnt available and dont touch anything when it is.